Clarifying a lemma and theorem from the book Irrational numbers by Ivan Niven.
Here, I present the lemma and the theorem, followed by an explanation of why I am confused.
Lemma 7.1
Any (r + 1) linear forms in (r) indeterminates with rational coefficients are linearly dependent over the rationals.
Remark. This is a well-known result, and so we give a reference but not a proof. The matrix of the linear forms cannot have rank greater than (r), and this is less than the number of forms. For further details, see any book on the theory of equations, for example:

J. M. Thomas, Theory of Equations, Theorem 27.7, p. 49, McGraw-Hill.


Theorem 7.2
Algebraic numbers are closed under addition and multiplication; in other words, the sum and the product of two algebraic numbers are themselves algebraic. More generally, algebraic numbers form a field.
Proof. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be algebraic numbers of degrees $m$ and $n$, respectively. Thus $\alpha$ satisfies an algebraic equation of degree $m$, say
$$
\alpha^m = a_{m-1} \alpha^{m-1} + a_{m-2} \alpha^{m-2} + \cdots + a_1 \alpha + a_0,
$$
with rational coefficients $a_j$. Thus, $\alpha^m$ is a linear combination of $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^{m-1}$ with rational coefficients. The same is true for $\alpha^{m+1}$, as can be seen by multiplying the equation above by $\alpha$ and then using it to replace the term $a_m \alpha^m$ by terms in $\alpha$ of lower degree. This process can be repeated, and so by mathematical induction, we see that each of $\alpha^m, \alpha^{m+1}, \alpha^{m+2}, \dots$ is expressible as a linear combination of $1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{m-1}$ with rational coefficients.
Similarly, each of $\beta^n, \beta^{n+1}, \beta^{n+2}, \dots$ is expressible as a linear combination of $1, \beta, \beta^2, \dots, \beta^{n-1}$ with rational coefficients.
Now consider the $mn + 1$ numbers:
$$
1, \alpha + \beta, (\alpha + \beta)^2, \dots, (\alpha + \beta)^{mn}.
$$
Expanding these and replacing the $m$-th and higher powers of $\alpha$ by the lower powers, and likewise the $n$-th and higher powers of $\beta$, we see that these $mn + 1$ numbers can be written as linear combinations of the $mn$ numbers
$$
\alpha^j \beta^k, \quad j = 0, 1, \dots, m - 1, \quad k = 0, 1, \dots, n - 1,
$$
with rational coefficients. These $mn$ numbers can be substituted for the $r$ indeterminates of Lemma 7.1, and so we conclude that the numbers $$
1, \alpha + \beta, (\alpha + \beta)^2, \dots, (\alpha + \beta)^{mn}.
$$   are linearly independent over the rationals. That is, $\alpha + \beta$ is an algebraic number.
The proof for the product $\alpha \beta$ is analogous, the powers of $\alpha + \beta$ in the above being replaced by the powers of $\alpha \beta$.

I am confused about the meaning of "linear forms" in this context. Does the book refer to homogeneous linear equations, or does it mean something akin to vectors?
Additionally, I am struggling to understand how this lemma is applied in the proof of the theorem of closure for algebraic numbers. Specifically:
In the proof, the book constructs the numbers $1, \alpha + \beta, (\alpha + \beta)^2, \dots, (\alpha + \beta)^{mn}$ and claims that these numbers are linearly independent over the rationals. However, the lemma talks about linear forms being linearly dependent. How do these two concepts relate?
How does Lemma 7.1 guarantee that $\alpha + \beta$ is algebraic?
Could someone clarify the interpretation of the term "linear forms," explain the connection between the lemma and the proof, and resolve the apparent contradiction between the notions of "linearly dependent" (in the lemma) and "linearly independent" (in the proof)?

"Linear form" means linear combination. "Linearly independent" is a typo for linearly dependent. That should clear everything up.

Care to engage?

@GerryMyerson The meaning of linear form to be linear combination is convincing but I am not sure that linearly independent is a typo, because he may use them to express the powers of $\alpha+\beta$ that are greater than $mn$, so to be honest, I am still confused, but I read another proof for the closure under addition from the book
An introduction to the theory of numbers by
Ivan Niven
Herbert S. Zuckerman
Hugh L. Montgomery
But I really want to clear my confusion about the proof included in my post here.
And I am thankful for your try to help and clear the confusion.

A linear form in $r$ indeterminates with rational coefficients is a function $(x_1, \dots, x_r) \mapsto a_1x_1 + \dots + a_r x_r$, defined on $\mathbb R^r$ with $a_1, \dots, a_r \in \mathbb Q$. Saying some of those are linearly dependent over the rationals means there is a linear combination of them with rational coefficients not all zero which equals zero (the zero linear form).
In the proof of the Theorem, Niven is saying that for $0 \leq k \leq mn$, $$(\alpha + \beta)^k = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} \alpha^j \beta^{k-j}$$ can be written as a linear combination with rational coefficients of $$1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}, \beta, \alpha \beta, \dots, \alpha^{n-1} \beta, \beta^2, \dots, \alpha^{n-1} \beta^{m-1}$$ because each term $\alpha^j$ and $\beta^{k-j}$ in the sum can be replaced by a linear combination with rational coefficients in $1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}$ and $1, \beta, \dots, \beta^{m-1}$ respectively, by the first paragraph.
In other words, there exist $a_{i, j, k} \in \mathbb Q$ depending on $k$, with $1 \leq i, j \leq mn$, such that one has $$(\alpha + \beta)^k = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} a_{i,j,k} \alpha^i \beta^j.$$ Now consider the linear forms $$f_k : (x_1, \dots, x_{mn}) \mapsto \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} a_{i,j,k} x_{i+nj}$$ for $0 \leq k \leq mn$. Those are $mn+1$ linear forms in $mn$ indeterminates, so by the Lemma, we know they are linearly dependent over the rationals (this is indeed a typo here in the book).
Thus, there exist $\lambda_0, \dots, \lambda_{mn} \in \mathbb Q$ not all zero such that $$\sum_{k=0}^{mn} \lambda_k f_k = 0.$$ Evaluating this linear form in the vector $(1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}, \beta, \alpha \beta, \dots, \alpha^{n-1} \beta, \beta^2, \dots, \alpha^{n-1} \beta^{m-1})$, this yields, $$\sum_{k=0}^{mn} \lambda_k (\alpha + \beta)^k = 0,$$ in other words, $\alpha + \beta$ is algebraic, since it is a root of the non-zero polynomial $$P(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{mn} \lambda_k X^k$$ with rational coefficients.

I am thankful for your help, this topic is really highly important to me, I was even willing to ask professor because it's really important to me, because I have high interest in algebraic and transcendental numbers, and I intend to study them to try to solve open problems in this topic, or at least contribute to this branch of mathematics, I am saying at least contribute because otherwise I would be cocky.
